# How to call a method after Vuex data is available?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I would like to call a method once, as soon as possible after its component loads, but it needs to be after a computed property that gets data from Vuex is defined.

For example:

```
  computed: {
    my_data: function() {
      return this.$store.state.my_data;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    useData: function(){
      axios.post('api/fetch', {'data': this.my_data});
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.useData(); //error: this.my_data is undefined;
  },
  watch: {
    my_data: function(){
      this.useData(); //never triggers
    }
  }
```

If I call this.useData() from mounted, my_data is still undefined. I tried setting a watcher on my_data, but it never triggers. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: The watch/method/race condition aside, `my_data` should be defined in `mounted` if it is defined already in Vuex.  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/54k0h2pr/). Can you show the Vuex state?

Comment: Your example is pretty confusing, since it looks like you are posting and then turning around and getting it from Vuex. Did you mean to use two different variables? Can you give a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: If `this.my_data` is undefined in `mounted()`, it means it doesn't exist in your `$store.state`. Any component getters calling `$store` getters or other state properties are exectuted before `mounted()` hook. Please post the relevant code from your Vuex store.

Comment: @Dan Turns out I had some wires crossed, but your comment that what I was trying *should* work helped point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the "undefined" error was caused by another object that shared a key name with my stored object. Unfortunately, the nebulous error message sent me on a wild goose chase after I assumed the stored object was the issue based on my inexperience with Vuex.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the data in `my_data` is updating correctly in store. If still have issue, then use `deep` to watch `my_data`

```
watch:{
  my_data:{
    handler:function(){
      this.userData();
    },
    deep:true
  }
}
```

If you're using watch to trigger method, don't need to use to call it from the `mounted`.